# How do I configure google cloud firewall for an instance to allow outside traffic?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I view my virtual machine server content outside of localhost. I think I need to create a firewall rule. I tried and still get a refused connection.

Comment: Can you post your firewall config please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a firewall rule that allows traffic to your VM instance.

Give the protocol and the port.

http://i63.tinypic.com/2mydwz6.png (screenshot)

Please refer to the below documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls